# Dynamic Range in Google Sheets Pivot Table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to build pivot table with dynamic range in "Google Sheets". Please help me with the same.

In Microsoft Excel we can achieve this with Offset function in pivot table. I am looking for similar solution.

I have tried using Named Range, Offset Function and also app script but none of them is working.

Comment: Thanks for your question; it is typical to provide some sample script/formula to show what you have tried and any errors or issues you have based on that.

Comment: I just tried in random way with knowledge of Microsoft Excel but that is not right way. So I can say I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A from StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574709/google-sheets-pivot-table-not-updating

Comment: There is an exmple [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/pivot) about updating pivot tables, in essence you're building it again with a new range, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Aleister. My data was starting from 2nd row. I changed it to 1st and followed this solution.

Comment: Thanks AMolina. I tried with app script to re-create but did not get required solution. So I gave entire like A:F.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is not available in Sheets in the same way it is in Excel. I recommend looking into the `query()` formula, which takes some more setup but is more powerful in many ways.

The Sheets documentation can be found [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) and I've found [this tutorial](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/) from Ben Collins to be extremely helpful in the past.

Comment: I now need to amend that Sheets has recently introduced their own Pivot support. Go to Data > Pivot table and you'll get some of the same functionality as Excel. Happy pivoting!

Answer (score 0):

If you are filling the entire Google spreadsheet - you can just use COLUMN names for full height and skip row numbers:
`your-source-sheet!A:Z`
Make sure you do not have empty rows at the bottom of the spreadsheet.

[image: specifying full height for pivot range]